# Не могу получить текст EditText

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Есть диалог

```
class DialogNewDir: DialogFragment() {

    interface ListenerNewDir {
        fun okButton(view: EditText)
        fun cancelButton()
    }

    private lateinit var listener: ListenerNewDir

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        try {
            listener = activity as ListenerNewDir
        } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
            throw ClassCastException(activity.toString() + "must implement ListenetNewDir")
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context!!)

        val inflater = activity!!.layoutInflater

        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_new_dir, null))
                .setMessage("")
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok) { dialogInterface, pos ->
                    listener.okButton(this.view!!.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edit_new_dir))

                }
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel) { _, _ ->
                    listener.cancelButton()
                }


        return builder.create()
    }

}
```

Я хочу передать ему виджет editText, чтобы получить текст, который был введён в диалоговом окне.
вот класс, где я хочу реализовать.

```
class ChoiceDirForButtons: AppCompatActivity(), DialogNewDir.ListenerNewDir {

 ...

    override fun okButton(edit: EditText) {

        val file = File(edit.text.toString())
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdir()
        }
        getListDirExistDataSet(dataSet)
    }

    override fun cancelButton() {
    }
```

View возвращает null и ничего поделать с этим не могу. как правильно получать данные, введенные в диалогах?

Comment: чам нужно передавать не виджет, а его содержимое, то есть, там, где этот виджет находится получить из него введенный текст и потом этот текст уже передавать дальше.

Comment: @pavlofff всё равно view или edit_new_dir возвращает null

Answer (score 0):

нужно оказывается получать view в отдельную переменную.

```
    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context!!)

        val inflater = activity!!.layoutInflater
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_new_dir, null)

        builder.setView(view)
                .setMessage("")
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok) { dialogInterface, pos ->
                    listener.okButton(view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edit_new_dir).text.toString())

                }
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel) { _, _ ->
                    listener.cancelButton()
                }


        return builder.create()
    }
```